# Installing GetFEM++ Using Msys

Tags: matlab, msys

I am trying to install the GetFEM++ library so that I can use it in MATLAB.   [This](http://mirko.windhoff.net/how_to/build_getfem_matlab_toolbox_on_windows_xp) guide is what I have been following to accomplish this.  I don't have any experience with msys so I am assuming I am missing something in its use.

Before going further, here is some general information on my system/where things are installed.

1) I untarred the package to C:\HOME\getfem.

2) I am using 64 bit Windows 8.1.

My problem is the first step of the guide. The entry to msys which I used (which is the same as the guide except with a changed path) is:

```
./configure \
--enable-matlab=yes \
--with-getfem-config=C:\HOME\getfem\getfem-config-notinstalled \ 
--with-toolbox-dir=C:\HOME\getfem_toolbox
```

The response I get is that there is no such file or directory.  Can someone direct me towards what may be going wrong?

Let me know if there is any other information I can provide to make the issue more clear.
Thanks in advance.